How do I make a list item the full height of it's content in IOS? (using a grid "*" row seems to be broken in IOS)
I have a list item in .net MAUI for IOS that is not working as expected. It appears that the issues lie in the fact that the grid visual elements within each individual item in the collection view are not expanding to the full height of the list item's content when their grid rows are set to have a grid row height of "*" after being made visible by a boolean. The code below demonstrates the issue that I am having:
Here is the xaml code Notice how I tried to even give the parent elements a fixed height from the collection view that needs to expand to the height of the parent collection view's 10000 unit height:
    <ContentPage.Content>
<Grid RowDefinitions="10000" BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond">
....
    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine">
        <VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ShowBusyOverlay, Converter={StaticResource not}}" HeightRequest="10000">
<CollectionView x:Name="sessionSummaryList" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSections}" HeightRequest="10000">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="datacollection:DataSection">
            <Grid>
                <!--Here is where the issue lies with the grid star "*" height in the collection view list item-->
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="10, 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.SectionTapped, Source={x:Reference Form} }" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource label}" MinimumHeightRequest="40" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource normalText}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Image  Source="{Binding Expanded, Converter={StaticResource expandedImageConverter}}" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Aspect="AspectFit" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Color="#b9b9b9"/>
                <!--This is where the expansion boolean is that I mentioned earlier "{Binding Expanded}"-->
                <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding Expanded}" ItemsSource="{Binding SectionItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionSelector}" EmptyView="No items to display" BackgroundColor="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
....
</VerticalStackLayout>
....
</VerticalStackLayout>
....
</Grid>
.......
</ContentPage>

Here is the current template of the "section selector"
Here is the c# view model expansion method tied to the Binding "Expanded" boolean mentioned earlier in the code behind:
public ICommand SectionTapped => new Command<SessionSummarySection>(OnSectionTapped);
//......
private void OnSectionTapped(SessionSummarySection sessionSummarySection)
{
    sessionSummarySection.Expanded = !sessionSummarySection.Expanded;

}

I also have an attached image of what the expected behavior should be please refer to that for more details on how this code should work:
enter image description here
As you can see, I have tried to get the layout to behave by setting the parent UI elements with a fixed height so that the grid can fill and expand in each item in the collection view according to the collection view's parent, but to no avail.
The only other way that I can think of to get this to work is by manually setting the height of each grid in each collection view element with hard values and not values like "6*" or "*" but that would mean I would have to add up the height of the content of each list item by grabbing the actual visual element tree from each grid with an x:Name reference or something like that (which I have no idea how to do). If anyone knows another way or can please show me how to get this to work that would be great.
Side notes, if I let the page re-render via hot reload, it will suddenly work for some reason, which means this is a MAUI-specific bug (I think). Another thing to note is that this solution needs to be cross platform with not only IOS, but android as well. So again, any advice on how to fix this issue would be very helpful indeed. Also, if you don't mind explicitly letting me know if the solution is free for me to use for a commercial project, let me know so that I can attribute you accordingly. Thanks! (If not, I will put my own spin on it, just to be safe.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-8.0#item-sizing

Thanks. I should have clarified that this was not an issue on android. In other words, the items that are in the list item behave as expected on android, but not on IOS when using the star grid row height parameter.

Thanks all. I was able to figure it out. So what I had to do was simply put "Auto" in place of the star (I feel like an idiot.) And then again give the list view and the surrounding container elements a fixed height. This works because the Collection View on iOS does not expand with its content, apparently. However, I did run into a new problem, the nested child element of the topmost parent in the proceeding collection view does not work when it is tapped with a tap gesture reader. I will open a new question on this soon.

Try this workaround
Try to Set Width or Height to -1 (Auto) if it did not work try to switch the values [iOS=-1,iOS=1,iOS=-1] while debugging, if it works as expected, plan to do it after CollectionView filled with data.
WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=-1,Default=1}"
HeightRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=-1,Default=1}"



<DataTemplate x:DataType="datacollection:DataSection">
     <Grid>
            <!--Here is where the issue lies with the grid star "*" height in the collection view list item-->
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               
                 ...
                 ...
                 
        <CollectionView WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=-1,Default=1}" 
                        HeightRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=-1,Default=1}"

                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                        IsVisible="{Binding Expanded}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding SectionItems}" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionSelector}" 
                        EmptyView="No items to display" 
                        BackgroundColor="White"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>


Thanks Mustafa. I am trying this out. I will let you know of the results soon.

Hmmm, this didn't work for me, when setting the collection view width and height requests as shown above. Interesting. Let me try setting this right after debugging.

@mbai you are welcome, try to set this also on the main Grid 


No, this didn't seem to work. I also tried setting the grid with the aforementioned values. Good guess though! I think this might be on the right track. Honestly though, Maui has been nothing but a mess. I will also try to look at what Jason sent me.

My suggestion to you to prevent nested collections, you will ran into a performance issue later , use popup insted to display the details . good luck

I would like to see if there is a way to get this working though.

The thing is, It would be far better to use the list views, I think

I'm using CollectionView with grouping, ListView is a desktop control, I think it will be deprecated from MAUI.
